# Output errado em C

Tags: c, array, scope

Estou fazendo uma atividade e o resultado está dando uns valores em que eu não atribuo em nenhum lugar do código.

```
int main(){

int numeroDePessoas = 0, tarefa = 0;

scanf("%d %d", &tarefa, &numeroDePessoas);

float passageiros[numeroDePessoas][5];

for(int i = 0; i < numeroDePessoas; i++){
    int classe, idade, numIrmaos, numFilhos;
    char sexo, porto;

    scanf("%d %c %d %d %d %c", &classe, &sexo, &idade, &numIrmaos, &numFilhos, &porto);

    passageiros[i][0] = (float)classe;

    if(sexo == 'f'){
        passageiros[i][1] = 1.0;
    } else {
        passageiros[i][1] = 0.0;
    }

    passageiros[i][2] = (float)idade;

    passageiros[i][3] = (float)numIrmaos;

    passageiros[i][4] = (float)numFilhos;

    if(porto == 'S'){
        passageiros[i][5] = 0.0;
    } else if(porto == 'C'){
        passageiros[i][5] = 1.0;
    } else if(porto == 'Q'){
        passageiros[i][5] = 2.0;
    }

}

// a tarefa 1 imprime a informação em forma númerica de todos os passageiros
if(tarefa == 0){

    for(int rows = 0; rows < numeroDePessoas; rows++){
        for(int cols = 0; cols < 6; cols++){
            printf("%.1f ", passageiros[rows][cols]);

            if(cols == 5){
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }

// imprime se o passageiro morreu ou sobreviveu dependendo de sua idade, classe e sexo (elementos 2, 0 e 1 respectivamentes)
} else if(tarefa == 1){

    for(int rows = 0; rows < numeroDePessoas; rows++){
        if( (passageiros[rows][2] > 15 && passageiros[rows][2] <= 45 ) || (passageiros[rows][0] > 1 && passageiros[rows][1] == 1) ){
            printf("Morreu\n");
        } else {
            printf("Sobreviveu\n");
        }
    }

// imprime a média da informação dos passageiros
} else if(tarefa == 2){
    float mClasse = 0.0, mSexo = 0.0, mIdade = 0.0, mNumIrmaos = 0.0, mNumFilhos = 0.0, mPorto = 0.0;

    for(int rows = 0; rows < numeroDePessoas; rows++){
        for(int cols = 0; cols < 6; cols++){


            if(cols == 0){
                mClasse += passageiros[rows][cols];

            } else if(cols == 1){
                mSexo += passageiros[rows][cols]; 

            } else if(cols == 2){
                mIdade += passageiros[rows][cols]; 

            } else if(cols == 3){
                mNumIrmaos += passageiros[rows][cols];

            } else if(cols == 4){
                mNumFilhos += passageiros[rows][cols];

            } else if(cols == 5){
                mPorto += passageiros[rows][cols];
            }
        }
    }

    mClasse /= numeroDePessoas;
    mIdade /= numeroDePessoas;
    mNumIrmaos /= numeroDePessoas;
    mNumFilhos /= numeroDePessoas;
    mSexo /= numeroDePessoas;
    mPorto /= numeroDePessoas;

    printf("%.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f", mClasse, mSexo, mIdade, mNumIrmaos, mNumFilhos, mPorto);
}

return 0;
```

}

Com o input:

`0
3
3 m 22 1 0 S
1 f 38 1 1 C
3 f 26 0 0 S`

Ele produz o output:

`3.0 0.0 22.0 1.0 0.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 38.0 1.0 1.0 3.0
3.0 1.0 26.0 0.0 0.0 0.0`

Mas o output desejado seria:

`3.0 0.0 22.0 1.0 0.0 0.0
1.0 1.0 38.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
3.0 1.0 26.0 0.0 0.0 0.0`

Não consigo ver onde esse 1.0, 3.0 e 0.0 vem dos elementos de index 5 de cada array mesmo rodando o programa pelo debugger diversas vezes.

Comment: Poderia colocar o enunciado da questão ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saudações!
O problema está no seguinte trecho de código:

```
float passageiros[numeroDePessoas][5];
```

Quando você declara um Array de tamanho 5, você deve pensar que a contagem começa do 0. Ou seja, você tem um array de 5 posições, que começa no zero. E um array de 5 posições que começa no zero, vai até o índice 4.

Ex.:

```
   passageiros[numeroDePessoas][0] = 2.0;  //São números aleatórios
   passageiros[numeroDePessoas][1] = 1.0;
   passageiros[numeroDePessoas][2] = 3.0;
   passageiros[numeroDePessoas][3] = 4.0;
   passageiros[numeroDePessoas][4] = 4.9;
   passageiros[numeroDePessoas][5] = 3.4; //ERRADO!!!!! ESSA JÁ É A POSIÇÃO 6!!
```

Se você tiver um array de 5 posições e chamar o índice número 5 dele, o sexto elemento, você provavelmente seja vítima dos famosos lixinhos que já estavam naquela posição de memória. Se você tiver sorte, o seu programa vai até funcionar, como foi o caso.

Experimente rodar esse:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){

int numeroDePessoas = 0, tarefa = 0;

scanf("%d %d", &tarefa, &numeroDePessoas);

float passageiros[numeroDePessoas][6]; //ALTEREI AQUI!!!

for(int i = 0; i < numeroDePessoas; i++){
    int classe, idade, numIrmaos, numFilhos;
    char sexo, porto;

    scanf("%d %c %d %d %d %c", &classe, &sexo, &idade, &numIrmaos, &numFilhos, &porto);

    passageiros[i][0] = (float)classe;

    if(sexo == 'f'){
        passageiros[i][1] = 1.0;
    } else {
        passageiros[i][1] = 0.0;
    }

    passageiros[i][2] = (float)idade;

    passageiros[i][3] = (float)numIrmaos;

    passageiros[i][4] = (float)numFilhos;

    if(porto == 'S'){
        passageiros[i][5] = 0.0;
    } else if(porto == 'C'){
        passageiros[i][5] = 1.0;
    } else if(porto == 'Q'){
        passageiros[i][5] = 2.0;
    }

}

// a tarefa 1 imprime a informação em forma númerica de todos os passageiros
if(tarefa == 0){

    for(int rows = 0; rows < numeroDePessoas; rows++){
        for(int cols = 0; cols < 6; cols++){
            printf("%.1f ", passageiros[rows][cols]);

            if(cols == 5){
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }

// imprime se o passageiro morreu ou sobreviveu dependendo de sua idade, classe e sexo (elementos 2, 0 e 1 respectivamentes)
} else if(tarefa == 1){

    for(int rows = 0; rows < numeroDePessoas; rows++){
        if( (passageiros[rows][2] > 15 && passageiros[rows][2] <= 45 ) || (passageiros[rows][0] > 1 && passageiros[rows][1] == 1) ){
            printf("Morreu\n");
        } else {
            printf("Sobreviveu\n");
        }
    }

// imprime a média da informação dos passageiros
} else if(tarefa == 2){
    float mClasse = 0.0, mSexo = 0.0, mIdade = 0.0, mNumIrmaos = 0.0, mNumFilhos = 0.0, mPorto = 0.0;

    for(int rows = 0; rows < numeroDePessoas; rows++){
        for(int cols = 0; cols < 6; cols++){


            if(cols == 0){
                mClasse += passageiros[rows][cols];

            } else if(cols == 1){
                mSexo += passageiros[rows][cols]; 

            } else if(cols == 2){
                mIdade += passageiros[rows][cols]; 

            } else if(cols == 3){
                mNumIrmaos += passageiros[rows][cols];

            } else if(cols == 4){
                mNumFilhos += passageiros[rows][cols];

            } else if(cols == 5){
                mPorto += passageiros[rows][cols];
            }
        }
    }

    mClasse /= numeroDePessoas;
    mIdade /= numeroDePessoas;
    mNumIrmaos /= numeroDePessoas;
    mNumFilhos /= numeroDePessoas;
    mSexo /= numeroDePessoas;
    mPorto /= numeroDePessoas;

    printf("%.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f %.3f", mClasse, mSexo, mIdade, mNumIrmaos, mNumFilhos, mPorto);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, ficou claro agora kkkk, obrigado pelo esclarecimento, agora consegui resolver! Nesse caso então o sistema/compiler jogava qualquer valor que encontrava pra suprir esse "sexto" index?

Comment: Eu considero C uma linguagem um tanto imprevisível. Dependendo do compilador que você estivesse usando, ou até mesmo do IDE, esse código seu teria a saída esperada. O que acontece é que, ao você utilizar uma posição de memória que você não declarou anteriormente, você está lidando diretamente com lixos(imprevisíveis) que já estavam lá. Ou até mesmo, roubando um espaço de memória de uma variável de outro programa. Nessa de fluxo de entrada e saída de dados, muita coisa fica pelo caminho. De certa forma, o que aconteceu foi o que você disse. Ele jogou qualquer valor que encontrou pelo caminho.